# $ F^{-1}(y) = \inf \{ t \in \mathbb R : F(t) \geq y \} $

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions

If I have a distribution F on the random variable Y, and if I set :

$$ F^{-1}(y) = \inf \{ t \in \mathbb R : F(t) \geq y \} $$

I think it also gives a distribution on another random variable.

Is it true ? Can someone give me an example of what the graph of such distribution would look like ? When the fonction the continuous and strictly increasing, it is easy because of the bijectivity. But what happens if the function is constant on a given interval or if it isn't continuous ? I'm stuck on such things.

Comment: $F^{-1}$ is called generalized inverse... searching for this term will give plenty of results, see e.g. [here](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~embrecht/ftp/generalized_inverse.pdf) for some basic properties of $F^{-1}$ (in particular the picture on page 3).

Comment: oh thank you ! I didn't know the name. I searched by the definition (the formula I wrote) and it gave me nothing on stack / google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reputation is to low to give a comment (so sorry to give an answer, but it's my only way to communicate with you). I answered to a question that may be helpful for you (even if it's not completely your question). [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158393/what-is-the-space-lp-mathbb-r-sim-where-f-sim-g-iff-f-and-g-has/3160506#3160506).